# Hazelcast EntryProcessor not working for CompactSerialization

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast.net

I am trying to use EntryProcessor with CompactSerialization with Hazelcast 5.2 version but getting below error:

Hazelcast.Protocol.RemoteException: 'com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.compact.DeserializedGenericRecord cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.map.EntryProcessor'

Can you please help and guide me what am I missing here? Is there anything need to configure from hazelcast.config side?

**My .NET Client side:**

```
public class MyTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroupLevel { get; set; }
    public int ItemFormContext { get; set; }
    public MyTest() { }
    public MyTest(int id, bool isGroupLevel, int itemFormContext)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.IsGroupLevel = isGroupLevel;
        this.ItemFormContext = itemFormContext;
    }
}
public class MyTestSerializer : ICompactSerializer\<MyTest\>
{
    public string TypeName => "MyTest";

    public MyTest Read(ICompactReader reader)
    {
        var ID = reader.ReadInt32("ID");
        var IsGroupLevel = reader.ReadBoolean("IsGroupLevel");
        var ItemFormContext = reader.ReadInt32("ItemFormContext");
        return new MyTest(ID, IsGroupLevel, ItemFormContext);
    }

    public void Write(ICompactWriter writer, MyTest value)
    {
        writer.WriteInt32("ID", value.ID);
        writer.WriteBoolean("IsGroupLevel", value.IsGroupLevel);
        writer.WriteInt32("ItemFormContext", value.ItemFormContext);
    }
}

public class UpdateEntryProcessor : MyTestSerializer, IEntryProcessor<MyTest>
{
    private MyTest value;
    public UpdateEntryProcessor(MyTest value = null)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    //Creating client
    var options = new HazelcastOptionsBuilder()
    .With(args)
    .WithDefault("hazelcast.networking.addresses.0", "\<ip address\>")   //Read Hazelcast server address from config file
    .WithDefault("hazelcast.clustername", "local")
    .WithDefault("hazelcast.socket.receive.buffer.size", "128")
    .WithDefault("hazelcast.socket.client.receive.buffer.size", "128")
    .WithDefault("hazelcast.socket.send.buffer.size", "128")
    .Build();
    options.Networking.ReconnectMode = Hazelcast.Networking.ReconnectMode.ReconnectSync;
    options.Serialization.Compact.AddSerializer(new MyTestSerializer());

    IHazelcastClient client = HazelcastClientFactory.StartNewClientAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var vpmap = client.GetMapAsync\<int, MyTest\>("vpMap").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    vpmap.SetAsync(1, new MyTest(1, false, 100)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var r1 = vpmap.GetAsync(1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    //update using entry processor
    vpmap.ExecuteAsync(new UpdateEntryProcessor(r1), r1.ID).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Can you please help and guide me what am I missing here? Is there anything need to configure from hazelcast.config side?

Comment: What do the Java side of the Entry processor implementation and its deserializer look like?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your server does not know **MyTest** type. So it is creating a **DeserializedGenericRecord** but your **EntryProcessor** expects **MyTest** and you are getting class cast exception
Either

1. You need to add **MyTest** to **classpath** of your server
2. or use U**ser Code Deployment (UCD)** from client side to upload **MyTest** to servers

See this question for some examples with UCD
[Deploy compactSerializer to hazelcast member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578522/deploy-compactserializer-to-hazelcast-member/77597865?noredirect=1#comment136812793_77597865)