# Deploy compactSerializer to hazelcast member

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I enabled user code deployment in hazelcast to use entry processors.
The entry processor and my entity classes are deployed to hazelcast, but the compact serializer is not deployed, so in the member side I get exception on serialization of my entity. How to deploy my compactSerializer from client side to hazelcast member and register it?

Answer (score 0):

Compact serializer can be used in two ways.

1. [With an explicit CompactSerializer](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/serialization/compact-serialization#implementing-compactserializer)
2. [With Zero-Configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/serialization/compact-serialization)

I am going to show you Zero Configuration, since your are using User Code Deployment (UCD).
Assume that you have class as below. This class does **not** implement a **serialization** mechanism.

```java
public class MyWorker {
  String name;
  
  public MyWorker(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MyWorker{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      '}';
  }
}
```

Also we have a EntryProcessor as below. **EntryProcessor** implements **Serializable**. So **MyWorkerEntryProcessor** is also serializable. I am returning **null** because I don't need updated map result on the client side.

```java
public class MyWorkerEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<Integer, MyWorker, MyWorker> {
  @Override
  public MyWorker process(Map.Entry<Integer, MyWorker> entry) {
    MyWorker newWorker = new MyWorker("new-worker1");
    entry.setValue(newWorker);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Start the server as below. **UCD** must be **enabled** on server side

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Config config = new Config();
  UserCodeDeploymentConfig ucdConfig = config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
  ucdConfig.setEnabled(true);

  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Let's have these helper methods on the client side.

```java
private static HazelcastInstance getHazelcastClientInstance() {
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

  // UCD
  ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig ucdConfig = clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
  ucdConfig.setEnabled(true);
  ucdConfig.addClass(MyWorker.class);
  ucdConfig.addClass(MyWorkerEntryProcessor.class);

  return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}

private static void populateMap(HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance) {
  IMap<Integer, MyWorker> myWorkerMap = hazelcastClientInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME);
  myWorkerMap.put(KEY, new MyWorker("worker1"));
}

private static void updateWorker(HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance) {
  IMap<Integer, MyWorker> myWorkerMap = hazelcastClientInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME);
  MyWorkerEntryProcessor entryProcessor = new MyWorkerEntryProcessor();
  myWorkerMap.executeOnEntries(entryProcessor);
}

private static void printWorker(HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance) {
  IMap<Integer, MyWorker> myWorkerMap = hazelcastClientInstance.getMap(MAP_NAME);

  MyWorker worker = myWorkerMap.get(KEY);
  LOGGER.info("New Worker : {}", worker);
}
```

Let's call them from client main

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // Start client
  HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance = getHazelcastClientInstance();

  // Do test
  populateMap(hazelcastClientInstance);
  updateWorker(hazelcastClientInstance);
  printWorker(hazelcastClientInstance);

  // Shut down HZ clien
  hazelcastClientInstance.shutdown();
}
```

So with zero config compact serialization I don't need to do anything. From the documentation you can see this sentence

> Compact serialization can also be used without registering a serializer in the member or client configuration.

HZ automatically creates a serializer for me. There are some constraints though. From the documentation again. So your class can have only certain member field types

> Currently, Hazelcast supports extracting schemas out of classes that have the field types shown above and some others, for user convenience.

For the explicit serialization case that I mentioned in the beginning, you need **register** a serializer to member, **not** deploy it. You can find examples in the documentation

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but I know about this. I use custom compact serializers, because I have some classes, also third party, for them zero-config can't work. So my question is, how to deliver my custom compact serializers also to server side?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for registering custom compact serializer from the client side.
On the client side have this class. This time I have used lombok to make to make the code shorter.

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class MyWorker {
  private final String name;
}
```

Have a serializer on the client side

```java
public class MyWorkerSerializer implements CompactSerializer<MyWorker> {
  @Override
  public MyWorker read(CompactReader compactReader) {
    String name = compactReader.readString("name");
    return new MyWorker(name);
  }

  @Override
  public void write(CompactWriter compactWriter, MyWorker myWorker) {
    compactWriter.writeString("name", myWorker.getName());
  }

  @Override
  public String getTypeName() {
    return "myworker";
  }

  @Override
  public Class<MyWorker> getCompactClass() {
    return MyWorker.class;
  }
}
```

Then start the client as below. The serializer is **added** to SerializationConfig

```java
 ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

// UCD
ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig ucdConfig = clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
ucdConfig.setEnabled(true);
ucdConfig.addClass(MyWorker.class);
ucdConfig.addClass(MyWorkerEntryProcessor.class);

clientConfig.getSerializationConfig()
  .getCompactSerializationConfig()
  .addSerializer(new MyWorkerSerializer());

HazelcastInstance hazelcastClientInstance =  
 HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Then use populateMap(),updateWorker(),printWorker() on the first answer

Comment: Are you sure that MyWorkerSerializer also will be deployed and registered on server side?

Comment: A serializer converts data to a byte array, allowing it to be transferred between clients and members. Therefore, you need a serializer on the client side. If your members also access data, you need to register the same serializer on the member side. You can achieve this using the provided code example, simply replacing "ClientConfig" with "Config" class. So MyWorkerSerializer  will not be deployed to server side in the provided example

Comment: So the answer to your question is, when you add a serializer from the client the Schema of the serializer is distributed to cluster members, not the serializer itself. Then the cluster members can create their own local serializers from the schema. I hope this helps